# Visualforce page error - Invalid Id: true

Tags: apex, visualforce, error, lightning-community, developer

Hope all are doing good!

I'm trying to open my visualforce page but I'm receiving an error called : **invalid id:true**

My page is working fine on yesterday but today Morning I'm receiving this error

I have tried in multiple browsers ,IE, Chrome, EDGE  getting same issue.

[image]

I'm trying to execute this code in Developer Console:

```
      List<ZTS_EU_Position__c> unAssignedUserTerrList=new List<ZTS_EU_Position__c>();
      //******* FILTER BY SYNCED TERRITORIES *********
      List<ZTS_EU_Position__c> custUsrTerrList = [SELECT Id, ZTS_EU_Employee__c, ZTS_EU_Territory__c,ZTS_EU_Territory__r.ZTS_EU_Terr_SFID__c FROM ZTS_EU_Position__c 
      WHERE ZTS_EU_Territory__r.ZTS_EU_Terr_SFID__c!='' AND ZTS_EU_Employee__c!='' AND Market__c != 'United States'];
      
      System.debug('custUsrTerrList'+custUsrTerrList);
      
      List<Id> stdTerrIds=new List<Id>();
      Set<Id> custUsrTerrIds=new Set<Id>();
               
      for(ZTS_EU_Position__c custUsrTerr:custUsrTerrList){
              custUsrTerrIds.add(custUsrTerr.ZTS_EU_Territory__c);
              stdTerrIds.add(custUsrTerr.ZTS_EU_Territory__r.ZTS_EU_Terr_SFID__c);
      }
      
      Map<Id,Territory2> stdTerrMap=new Map<Id,Territory2>([SELECT Id , ZTS_Terr_SFID__c FROM Territory2 WHERE Id IN :stdTerrIds]);
      //CHECK FOR ROWS FETCHED
      List<UserTerritory2Association> stdUsrTerrList=[SELECT UserId, Territory2Id FROM UserTerritory2Association WHERE Territory2Id IN :stdTerrIds];
      Set<String> stdUsrTerrUniqKeySet=new Set<String>();
      for(UserTerritory2Association usrTerr:stdUsrTerrList){
              stdUsrTerrUniqKeySet.add(usrTerr.UserId+':'+stdTerrMap.get(usrTerr.Territory2Id).ZTS_Terr_SFID__c);
              
      }
                
      for(ZTS_EU_Position__c custUsrTerr:custUsrTerrList){
              String usrTerrUniqKey=custUsrTerr.ZTS_EU_Employee__c+':'+custUsrTerr.ZTS_EU_Territory__c;
              System.debug('usrTerrUniqKey : '+usrTerrUniqKey+'\n');
              if(!stdUsrTerrUniqKeySet.contains(usrTerrUniqKey)){
                      unAssignedUserTerrList.add(custUsrTerr);
                  
              }System.debug('unAssignedUserTerrList::::'+unAssignedUserTerrList);
      }
```

This code giving an error but not sure which line results this error.

If any one having idea on this error kindly please suggest some ideas.

Thanks In advance,
Raghu

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read about [ask], and take the [tour]. We would have to see your code to help you. What we can immediately say is that you're trying to assign the value of the string `true` to a variable in Apex defined as an `Id`. Changing your browser would have no effect, as this is a server-side problem. You can [edit] your question to include your code, and we'd be happy to take a look at it with you.

Comment: @sfdcfox Thanks for the quick response. I have updated the code which results error but not sure from which line it is getting an error. Kindly help on this.

Comment: @Raghu, may I ask: What type has the field ZTS_EU_Territory__c of ZTS_EU_Position__c ? As sfdcfox pointed out, you are assigning a Boolean or String "true" to an Id. (Maybe in the line where you add this field to custUsrTerrIds?) Note also that you can identify the exact line number with the error by looking at your log file in the Developer Console.

Comment: What kind of a field is ZTS_EU_Territory__r.ZTS_EU_Terr_SFID__c? If it's a text field, or some kind of a text formula, it might have a value of TRUE on one of your ZTS_EU_Territory__c records.